# SQL/PHP - Check if user already liked post and if yes unlike?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, pdo

So I have these tables.

**Table: Likes**

**user_id :** The user that logged in

**post_id :** The article where the user clicked like.

[image]

Then I have a Like.class.php which stores the getters and setters and the functions.

I have two right now, **Addlike();** which enters the id (auto increment) and the user_id and post_id of the article/posts he liked.

Countlike(); counts the entries with a simple `rowCount();` of all the rows.

```
public function Addlike($postid){

        $conn = db::getInstance();
        $query = "insert into likes (post_id, user_id) values (:post_id, :user_id)";
        $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':post_id',$postid);
        $statement->bindValue(':user_id',$this->getUserId());
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }

    public static function Countlike(){
        $conn = db::getInstance();
        $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from likes");
        $statement->execute();
        $likecount =  $statement->rowCount();
        return $likecount;
    }
```

**My question**: How can I now check if the user already liked the post (out of the DB) and if he presses like again it should remove his entry from the DB, any ideas on how I can turn this into code? Also the likes need to be bonded to the posts for example, every post has it own like counter/number

Comment: Look for a row `WHERE post_id = ? AND user_id = ?`, if found, delete (dislike) otherwise we need to show like icon / image / link.

Comment: the easiest is to do it in 2 separate queries, a `select` to check if the like exists for these user and post ids, then delete based on the `id` if a result is found. It's also possible to do it in a single query, but that's more advanced SQL

Comment: @Kaddath Can you explain it a bit more? Thanks

Comment: Panic, feel free to check out the code I wrote for a hobby website I made on git here: https://github.com/colokurt/sharks_cms . I have the same functionality that you are asking for that gets handled in a few different php files. You can see the functionality here:  http://sjsharktank.com/cms/page.php?id=7046  Note: it is sqlite, but you can use the same concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it in the DB

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE post_id=:post_id AND user_id=:user_id
```

Another way is to write into COOKIES or better Web Storage id of posts liked by user.

More into code :

```
private function Addlike($postid){
    $conn = db::getInstance();
    $query = "insert into likes (post_id, user_id) values (:post_id, :user_id)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':post_id',$postid);
    $statement->bindValue(':user_id',$this->getUserId());
    $statement->execute();
}
private function Deletelike($postid){
    $conn = db::getInstance();
    $query = "DELETE FROM likes WHERE post_id = :post_id AND user_id =:user_id";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':post_id',$postid);
    $statement->bindValue(':user_id',$this->getUserId());
    $statement->execute();
}

public function CheckLike($postid){
    $conn = db::getInstance();
    $query = "LECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE post_id=:post_id AND user_id=:user_id";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':post_id',$postid);
    $statement->bindValue(':user_id',$this->getUserId());
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($result["COUNT(*)"] == 0){
        $this->Addlike($postid);
    }else{
        $this->Deletelike($postid);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this input! A teammate fixed it for us already, but the way of thinking is similar

Answer (score 0):

As i said in the comment, the simplest in term of SQL is to use 2 separate queries. For your use case, this should be allright, the query doesn't deal with multiple rows/values.

There actually should be some verifications after your queries too, in case you have a SQL error, i haven't added them.

NOTE: in good practices, names beginning by capitals are usually reserved for Classes, functions are commonly in camel-case like in the following:

```
public function delLike($postid){
    $conn = db::getInstance();
    $query = "SELECT id from likes WHERE post_id=:post_id AND user_id=:user_id";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':post_id',$postid);
    $statement->bindValue(':user_id',$this->getUserId());
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //there should be only one result at this point
    if(!empty($result)){
        $query = "DELETE from likes WHERE id=:id";
        $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':id',$result[0]['id']);
        $statement->execute();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As a side note, you could use a single query with combining `select`, `delete` and `exists`, you have [examples here](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/delete-statement-using-the-exists-or-not-exists)